# Fallback for gpuArray on machines that don't support CUDA

Tags: matlab, gpu

I am working with a project that contains many lines looking like:

```
W = gpuArray(x, y);

// or...
W = zeros(x, y, 'gpuArray');
```

This code fails on a machine that does not support CUDA.

I'm quite surprised `gpuArray` doesn't natively fall back.

Can anyone suggest a tidy strategy for adapting the code so that it only  attempts to use CUDA on a machine that supports it?

Answer (score 2):

I personally do it like this in my code: I initialize one array either on GPU or CPU, depending on a boolean (I have put ...Parameters.UseGPU which chooses this).

```
if (Parameters.UseGPU)
   W = gpuArray(x,y);
else
   W = zeros(x,y);
end
```

Then I use 'like' in subsequent allocations:

```
W2 = zeros(x,y,'like',W);
```

This lets me play with sparse, gpuArray and similar, depending on the flags I have put in my Parameters.

This works for me, as I have rather few entry points and it is simple enough to make sure all class properties are of the correct type - I look at this parameter once and have everything of the same type, even if it changes later.

But I don't think it would be a viable approach when you have tons of various functions that need to initialize arrays and are not given an array of suitable type as input. In that case, I believe I would write a function like

```
function arr = initialize(x, y) % or varargin or whatever.
   if (Param.UseGPU) 
     W = gpuArray(x, y);
     %etc
   end
end
```

In this case you should have that UseGPU as a read-only persistent thingy that checks whether suitable GPU is present when it is used for the first time. Mixing things isn't really a big problem, Matlab handles the conversion to GPU just fine. It is just that you might believe you are not using GPU anymore, but tons of arrays are still GPU ones, and you are doing needless conversion and sending of data around = slow.